# Where are implemented the functions getDownloadableData and setDownloadableData for Mage_Catalog_Model_Product in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to modify the  Downloadable Information / Links of a product programmability.

I am able to create a downloadable product. 
But I can't find how to edit the links.

I think the fonction setDownloadableData / getDownloadableData could help me.

But, i can't find them in the Magento source (1.7.0.2).

with

```
grep -r "setDownloadableData" magento/*
```

I can only see the call to the function. Not the implementation. ...

```
    /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Link/Api.php
$product->setDownloadableData($downloadable);
    /magento/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Observer.php
$product->setDownloadableData($downloadable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Varien Data Collections

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the methods because they don't exist.
Most of the classes in Magento extend `Varian_Object` class that overloads the 'magic method' `__call`. This is called when a method in the class does not exist.
To get a better view on this take a look at `Varien_Object::__call()`, [this article](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-find-methods-in-magento.html) and [what php.net has to say about overloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)